# Dynamic paths in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I searched through a lot of questions but hasn't found answer.
I use handlebars templates and have data structure:

```
{
  privileged_users: [ "user1", "user2" ],
  users: {
    user1: { name: "N1" },
    user2: { name: "N2" },
    user3: { name: "N3" }
  }
}
```

I wan't to output all privileged users with some template. Something like this:

```
<table>
  {{#each privileged_users}}
     <tr><td>{{../users.[this].name}}</td></tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

Is it possible without additional helpers?

If it isn't how can I write block helper with changing context to ../users.[this] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register following helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('lookupProp', function (obj, key, prop) {
   return obj[key] && obj[key][prop];
});
```

Then modify the template like:

```
<table>
  {{#each privileged_users}}
     <tr><td>{{lookupProp ../users this 'name'}}</td></tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

<strike>Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xak2udw/1/).</strike>
Previous one is just a simple expression helper.

Now here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xak2udw/4/) according to question.

Handlebars has a built-in lookup [helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) since version 3.0.3.
An alternate to block helper could be Handlebars [Partial Context](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html) approach i.e. define/register a partial and use it with different context in main template.

Comment: You answer is about what to avoid - write full path to each attribute of user. Question was "If it isn't how can I write block helper with changing context to ../users.[this] ?".

Comment: I have updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xak2udw/4/) having a *block helper* and tried to explain how it works.